# How to prevent put business logic code on DAL layer when you need a ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, architecture

My application is build from 3 layer: GUI, BLL and DAL. DAL's using store procedure to work with database and BLL contains business logic C# code.

Sometime, I force to put business logic code on DAL layer because I need a "ID" (auto identity) to able to continue writing business C# code. I think that this architect is too tight! So, Is there any way to make it loose ?

For example:

1.Insert a new object A (student). (ID, name, age, sex)

2.Insert a new object B (score) with need ID of A. (ID, point, studentID, subjectID)

3.Count number of point > 5 with subjectID = 1 (Math)

- the store procedure for insert "student", also "core" is very simple.
- the store procedure for counting point > 5 is simple too.

At BLL layer:

```
public int? methodA(Object A, Object B){
   return DAL.methodA(A,B)
}
```

At DAL layer:

```
public int? methodA(object A, Object B){
   int? result = null;
   using(sqlconnection conn){
     using(sqltraction trans){
        IDstudent = sp_InsertStudent(A)
        ObjectB.Idstudent = IDstudent 
        IDscore = sp_InsertScore(B)
        result = sp_CountPointOver5(IDst)    
     }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Above is a small example. In realty, I have to write a lot of business logic at DAL layer inside sqltransaction after get studentID. For example: After get studentID, I will call 4 method to complete business logic. These 4 method is all write from C# code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. There isn't even a real question here. Just a vague reference with nothing resembling enough substance for an answer.

Comment: As a follow-up Sean's comment, consider adding a couple small code blocks, that's always helpful in trying to visualize what you're doing.

Comment: Alright, I will update my question now! @OperatorOverload

Answer (score 0):

There are several good ways to decouple this.  The most common way is to have your DAL Layer just have a "persist" method for Student, which will return a student entity with the ID filled in.  This will then allow you to insert a Score, passing the student entity in (with ID).

If you need transactions (an assertion you should strongly evaluate), then the most common method is to pass a DBContext around.  You can of course use a Connection, but that binds you to your persistence layer a little too tightly (IMHO).  Regardless, that allows you to scope your transactions at the BLL scope, while not actually binding to the DAL layer too tightly.